# How to apply middleware in nest.js for module other than ApplicationModule?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Im trying to apply middleware based on config like so:

```
export class UsersModule implements NestModule{
  configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer): void {
    const authRoutes = UsersController.getAuthRoutes();
    consumer
      .apply(AuthMiddleware)
      .forRoutes(...authRoutes);
  }
}
```

method `getAuthRoutes` is static:

```
  public static getAuthRoutes(){
    return [
      { path: `/api/users`, method: RequestMethod.ALL},
    ];
  }
```

My AuthMIddleware is pretty basic:

```
@Middleware()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    @Inject(constants.logger) private logger: Winston,
  ){}

  resolve(...args: any[]): ExpressMiddleware {
    // return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
    return (req, res, next) => {
      this.logger.debug('AuthMiddleware');
      next();
    };
  }
}
```

It just logs line in console. Im trying to access via get request /api/users, im getting list of users, but no AuthMiddleware message in console. Any advices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See my issue [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/453). Its just misunderstanding of documentation.